# FileConverter for Log4J2

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I am working on a project to convert logging from log4j 1.x to log4j 2.x.
For Rolling File Appender I need to create filename that should have the pid of the
service appended in it. For **Ex:**
In log4J 1.x it is defined as below:

```
<appender name="FILE" class="com.app.util.log4j.RollingFileAppender ">
        <param name="File" value="${app.home}/logs/@{pid}-app.log"/> 
<appender />
```

Now, as per the log4j 2.x documentation, to achieve the same, I should write a Converter
plugin of type File Converter [doc](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.7/manual/plugins.html#Converters).
But, I am not able to find any details like which class needs to be extended and any
sample code related to File Converter.
Please help to achieve this goal. Thanks in advance...!!!

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

There are two kinds of placeholders you can use to generate the name of the old log file after a rollover:

- pattern converters `%key{...}` in the "FileConverter" category. Log4j2 passes the old logfile's creation date and index number to these converters. There are only two of them: the date pattern `%d{...}` (cf. [source code](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/release-2.x/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/pattern/FileDatePatternConverter.java)) and the index pattern `%i` (cf. [source code](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/release-2.x/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/pattern/IntegerPatternConverter.java)) and they must implement [`ArrayPatternConverter`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/pattern/ArrayPatternConverter.html).
- lookups `${key:value}`, which don't have access to the two values mentioned above.

Since the process id of the JVM does not change in time, you don't need pattern converters and:

- if the Java system properties `app.base` and `pid` are set, you can use the system properties lookup:

  ```xml
  <RollingFile name="RollingFile"
               fileName="${sys:app.base}/logs/${pid}-app.log"
               filePattern="${sys:app.base}/logs/${sys:pid}-app.log.%i">
      ...
  </RollingFile>
  ```
- otherwise you can extend, e.g. the [`JavaLookup`](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/release-2.x/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/lookup/JavaLookup.java) with a "pid" property (you can exploit the [`ProcessIdUtil`](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/release-2.x/log4j-api/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/util/ProcessIdUtil.java) to do it) and PR the modified version to the Log4j2 project.